# visual studio code external exception c0000006

Tags: exception

everytime i try to install VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.71.2 i get this pop up "external exception c0000006 " it pops 3 times. i have tried a few things there and there, but to no avail. i then formated my computer but the issue persist.

i am really lost here. i have found this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/previous-versions/troubleshoot/visualstudio/foxpro/c0000006-error-troubleshooting-suggestion)
but it did not help my case.

i have downloaded the entire package and it works from there but the thing is i am now getting the same problem when i tried to install audacity. it seems i need to get to the bottom of this. i keep looking online but i cant find anything yet. if i could at least get a direction that would be great. all i could figure out is it is a network error, although that error poped out one day out of nowhere.

i am runing win10 professional edition 64

Comment: That normally requires a serious hardware failure, indicating a bad disk drive.  Perhaps not that much of a surprise when you so routinely try to solve problems by formatting the disk.  Could be crummy anti-malware.

Comment: i format once every 2 years

Comment: thanks for you comment. now I know it's not something i can fix unless i replace the hdd. as for formatting i dont format when it gets tought. formating and reinstalling takes a day. it was just overdue and that issue was the last straw.